# Recovering/Removing the BIOS password of a Toshiba Satellite M35-S320

Tags: laptop, bios, passwords, toshiba-laptop, hashing

I have this Toshiba Satellite M35-S320, with a BIOS password. The problem is, I was a bonehead and had no idea what I was doing when I set a (random) password.

I forgot the password immediately.

Is there any way to reset or recover the BIOS password?
Remember, I CANNOT BOOT INTO THE OS, BOOT MENU, BIOS SETUP, ANYTHING. I am locked out of this thing.
A thing I would like to know:

Some people on the internet talk about BIOS password [hashes](https://dogber1.blogspot.com/2009/05/table-of-reverse-engineered-bios.html). This "hash"

does not appear when I fail. It just says, "Too many attempts! The system will 
be powered off!"

***Note: I have already tried removing the battery, trying "Toshiba", and holding down the Left Shift key.***

I really hope I can get this thing working. :(

Comment: If anybody wants to point me to other StackExchange sites, tell me those sites and I'll put this up there.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used a Satellite in years, but doing some research, I find several possible options:

1. Try 'Toshiba' as a password.
2. Hold left-shift key down during boot.
3. Open the PC and remove the battery for at least an hour.

Comment: Sorry, have already tried that stuff. Did not work. Thanks though!

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: @TheUbuntuMaster Three more ideas: 1. Try 'toshiba' in lower case. 2. Hold 0 (zero) key then press and release power button, then release 0 key when it starts beeping. 3. Remove RTC battery (and main battery): search for image d7f1d05a-246a-403d-a938-a4c851df379e.jpg on google, which is visible in Google Images, but not on source site.